# Algebra subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find, if the following set is the subspace of $R^3$:

$A = {(x,y,z): x + y + z = a, a \in\mathbb{R} } $

I don't understand if I had to prove it for certain $a$ or for $a$ as real number.

$(W,K,+,*)$ is a subspace of $R^3$ <=>

1) $\forall x, y \in W => x + y \in W $;  2).  $\forall a \in K$  $\forall x \in W => a*x \in W $

$\vec{c} =$$(\frac{3}{5}a,\frac{1}{5}a,\frac{1}{5}a)= \frac{3}{5}a + \frac{1}{5}a + \frac{1}{5}a = a \in \mathbb{R} $

$\vec{b} =$$(\frac{1}{3}a,\frac{1}{3}a,\frac{1}{3}a)= \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{1}{3}a = a \in \mathbb{R} $

but $\vec{c}+\vec{b} = 2a \neq a $

So it's not a subspace. Is it a correct prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,proof is correct.But you do not have to write a and b as (3a/5,a/5,a/5) or (a/3,a/3,a/3).You can just take two elements from the set A;for instance (k,l,m) and (p,r,s).Then their sum would be (k+p,l+r,s+m).And above condition says that (k+p)+(l+r)+(s+m) should be equal to a.But we see that (k+p)+(l+r)+(s+m)=(k+l+m)+(p+r+s)=a+a=2a which is not equal to a.So,this set cannot be a subspace of ${R^3}$.